# If there is string.Empty why there is not char.Empty?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no Char.Empty like String.Empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670505/why-is-there-no-char-empty-like-string-empty)

I want to pass an empty char as a method parameter and I was wondering why I cannot say

```
char.Empty
```

while C# allows me to specify `string.Empty` ?

If not do I have '' as the only option ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no empty char same way there is no empty number.

You can try using "null" character:

```
char empty = '\0';
```

Comment: Sorry posted this before noticing the duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use for identifying empty char:

```
default(Char)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an empty char. You would need to use nullable types to introduce that concept.

```
char? c = null;
```