# What is the difference between "" and " ", and how do I test the former in terms of a char? 

Tags: java, char, string

In Java, what is the difference between "" (empty quotes) and " " (quotes with a single space) and how do I test the former in terms of a `char`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`""` represents the empty string. `" "` is **not** empty, it contains a single space character.

You can't test the former in terms of a `char`, as there are no characters: test for it in terms of a `String`: it is the `String` of length zero, and `String.equals("")` returns `true` for the empty string.

Or in terms of `char` *arrays*, the empty string corresponds to the `char` array of length zero, e.g.:

```
char noChars[] = new char[0];
String str = new String(noChars);
// now str is the empty String
```

Comment: I tried testing for the null character '\0' but it seems that is also not equivalent to an empty string. I also found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3670520) which explained why.

Answer (score 4):

`""` - Is an Empty String, and it has a lenght of zero, try calling `length()` method on it.

`" "` - A String with 1 space.

Answer (score 3):

```
“” - Empty Sting - String with 0 length
“ ” - single space - String with 1 length
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `""` and `" "` are String objects which are 0 and 1 in length respectively.
Here is their content representation in terms of char primitives:

```
"" - empty char[] array
" " - char[] { ' ' } :- Char aray with single char entry
```

Best to use `String.equals` when comparing the contents of strings. Here just a `length()` check is necessary though.