# how to set a value of char array to null?

Tags: c#, arrays, null, char

for example when I wrote:

```
Char[] test = new Char[3] {a,b,c};
test[2] = null;
```

it says **Cannot convert null to 'char' because it is a non-nullable value type**

if I need to empty that array of char, is there a solution?

Comment: see [Why is there no Char.Empty like String.Empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3670505/944681)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a nullable char:

```
char?[] test = new char?[3] {a,b,c};
test[2] = null;
```

The drawback is you have to check for a value each time you *access* the array:

```
char c = test[1];  // illegal

if(test[1].HasValue)
{
    char c = test[1].Value;
}
```

or you could use a "magic" char value to represent `null`, like `\0`:

```
char[] test = new char[3] {a,b,c};
test[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: Just a quick suggestion might be to use `default(char)` for the "magic" value.  IMHO, it provides a similar mental model for considering the value "uninitialized" or "unspecified."

Comment: Fair enough - using `\0` as `null` is a holdover from my C++ days :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with that...  They are the same in this case, after all.

Comment: that '\0' works perfectly. I'm sorry I have to ignore the first 2 packs of codes above because I'm searching for the simplest one. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it because, as the error says, char is a value type.

You could do this:

```
char?[] test = new char?[3]{a,b,c};
test[2] = null;
```

because you are now using the nullable char.

If you don't want to use a nullable type, you will have to decide on some value to represent an empty cell in your array.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, `char` is non-nullable.  Try using `default` instead:

```
test[2] = default(char);
```

Note that this is essentially a null byte '`\0`'.  This does not give you a `null` value for the index.  If you truly need to consider a `null` scenario, the other answers here would work best (using a nullable type).

Comment: `default(char)` gives [the null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). Why not make that explicit and say `test[2] = '\0';`? I would recommend that (if you want to use this character as a kind of "magic value").

Comment: Only for consistency...  I use `default` in many cases where the type is not know up front (i.e. generics or reflection).  It helps me keep a consistent mental model that `default` => "unspecified" or "uninitialized."

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

`test[2] = Char.MinValue;`

If you had tests to see if a value was "null" somewhere in your code, you'd do it like this:

```
if (test[someArrayIndex] == Char.MinValue)
{
   // Do stuff.
}
```

Also, `Char.MinValue == default(char)`

Answer (score 1):

you can set test to null

```
test = null;
```

but not test[2] because it is char - hence value type

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason for your question, but if instead you use `List<>`, you could say

```
List<char> test = new List<char> { a, b, c, };
test.RemoveAt(2);
```

This changes the length (`Count`) of the `List<>`.