# Remove slashes from date and file extension from string

Tags: c#, regex, string-parsing

I need to do two things with strings:
A. Remove the file extension
B. Remove the '-' from the dates.

An example of an uploaded string is:

> ifrs_au-cor_2013-03-12.xsd

I can't just do a replace on '-' because the first part of the string contains a '-' that I don't want removed, only the date ones.  However, the date will always be in YYYY-MM-DD format and it will be at the end with the extension.

Currently I only have the following code to remove the extension from the string:

```
String xsdfnameNoExtNoSlash = xsdfname;
int fileExtPos = xsdfname.LastIndexOf(".");
if (fileExtPos >= 0 )
  xsdfnameNoExtNoSlash = xsdfname.Substring(0, fileExtPos);
```

Is there any way to do both of these operations in one go?

Comment: I guess a regular expression may help here, but to be honest, what's the advantage of doing this in 1 go. I don't think this is really needed.

Comment: Not at all a requirement just, no problem with two different strings.  Was just wondering if there was a regex or some way to do it in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);
return Regex.Replace(name, @"(?<!\d)(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)(?!\d)", "$2$3$4");
```

This first removes the extension (if present), and then finds all dates and removes slashes from them.

The regex uses lookahead and lookbehind to ensure that something like "92012-01-019" is not considered a date. Anything other than a digit is accepted as a date boundary. You can tweak this if necessary, for example, if "92012-01-019" *should*, in fact, be changed to "9201201019" then you can just remove the lookahead/lookbehind (and change the numbers in the replacement string).

I think it's easiest to remove the extension as a separate step, rather than trying to do it all in one go.

Comment: Nice, and your conclusion is also correct in my opinion. Doing it with a regex makes it almost unreadable :)

Comment: running the code is giving me:  ifrs_au-cor_0312$4 - its removing the year and adding a $4 also.

Answer (score 0):

```
string noslash = withslash.Replace('-', '');
string noextension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xsdfname);
```

Comment: Even if the Replace method were applicable here, the string version would have to be used, seeing as there is no empty character literal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670505/why-is-there-no-char-empty-like-string-empty for more information.

Comment: Oops, missed the requirement.  In that case, you woud need a regex replace.