# yield return empty character literal

Tags: c#, linq, char, yield-return

I'm writing a Linq extension method, to make a p455w0rd from a string input.

```
public static IEnumerable<char> ToPasswordFormat(this IEnumerable<char> source)
{
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            switch((char)enumerator.Current)
            {
                case 'a':
                    yield return '4';
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    yield return '3';
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    yield return '7';
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    yield return '!';
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    yield return '';
                    break;
                default:
                    yield return (char)enumerator.Current;
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

as you can see I want to remove spaces, but when I use `yield return '';` it gives me error `Empty character literal`.

What is `''` and how can I return yield return nothing?

Comment: Just don't yield anything, carry on in your while loop. i.e. `case ' ': break;`

Comment: You could return `'\0'`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3670513/284240

Comment: Rather than using a giant `switch` I suggest you just build a `Dictionary<char, char>` to map the values; it will be much simpler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot `yield return nothing`. The solution would be to **not** yield return if it's a whitespace. Comment out that line and you should be good.

`''` is meaningless. The compiler will complain. There is no such thing as "no character".

Comment: +1 The key is that given `'1','2',' ','3'` you don't want a sequence like `'1','2','','3'`. You don't want the `' '` replaced with anything at all, so just don't `yield` anything.

Comment: `There is no such thing as "no character".` Well, actually, there is.  `'\0'`.  The "null character".  That said, it shouldn't be used in this context.

Comment: The nul character is a valid character. It has a defined value. It has a special meaning for many programming languages, but it's still a character. "No character" cannot exist the same way that "no int" cannot exist, although we frequently speak of "no money" when we mean zero :)

Comment: @nvoigt No character (or no int) can certainly exist. You would just need to change the type from `char` to `char?`.

Comment: @svick Even a Nullable char always has a value. It only has an *additional* bool value telling you if the value of the char is useful to you or just random garbage. But it has a value, even a char? cannot have "no value". You can test it, check the value of the char in the nullable char if the HasValue bool is false. It's still a char with a value.

Comment: @nvoigt Well, that depends on what exactly does “has a value” mean. If you look at it technically, then yeah, it's a `struct` that has a fields set to `false` (so it has a value). But logically, this value represents a state without a value, just like real `null` does for reference types. And most of the time, you care about the logical meaning of code, not about its implementation.

Comment: @nvoigt, what if I want to do a replace with: Replace('*', '') so that I replace the asterisk with no space. How can I do that?

Comment: @KalaJ That seems to be a different question. You may want to do a search for your question here and if you don't find an answer, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

1. `''` is meaningless. There is no concept of "no character" - there is the nul character, but it is not the same as "no character". Compare this with strings, which can be a null reference (to a string) or a zero-length string.
2. Already answered in a comment to your question by @George Duckett: Just remove the `yield` from the `' '` case.