# Why is there no empty char literal?

Tags: c#, char, language-design

Is there any specific reason why there is no empty `char` literal?

What comes closest to what I think of, the `''` is the `'\0'` the null character.

In `C++` the `char` is represented by an `int`, which means empty char goes directly to the 0 integer value, which is in C++ "the same as null".

The practical part of coming up with that question:

In a class I want to represent char values as enum attributes.
Unbiased I tried to initialize an instance with `''`, which of course does not work.
But shouldn't be there a `char` null value? Not to be confused with `string.Empty`, 
more in the nature of a `null reference`.

So the question is: Why is there no empty char?

-edit-

Seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670505/why-is-there-no-char-empty-like-string-empty) the question can be enhanced on:
An empty char value would enable concatening strings and chars without
destroying the string. Would that not be preferable? Or should this
"just work as expected"?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670505/why-is-there-no-char-empty-like-string-empty

Comment: No duplicate, as the question goes on the Char class, where I want to know about the design decision behind that.

Comment: char is a primitive type. A null char makes no more sense than a null int

Comment: I already saw that comment, so what about `int?` Does this not make sense either? This is clearly a design decision and there are certainly clear reasons for that. A null char would be... empty. The total sum of all character in string.Empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a slightly more technical explanation: There is no character that can serve as the [identity element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) when performing concatenation. This is different from integers, where `0` serves as the identity element for addition.

Comment: as 1 does for multiplication, and this is exactly what I'm asking. Why is it not there?

Comment: @MareInfinitus concatenating two chars 'a' and 'b' would not give a char. Why would you expect there to be a special value where it would?

Comment: @Lee: Read the last part of the question (after it was edited). This is all about identities.

Comment: @bengiesboom: I would expect concatening `'a'` and `''` to give a string of length one.

Comment: More concrete: I would expect concatening `'a'` + `''` + `'b'` to give a string of length two, whereas `'a'` + `'\0'` + `'b'` gives a string of length one.

Comment: I don't think it is fair to compare charactor concatenation to integer addition. You can add the null charator to any charactor and receive the same charactor (requires a cast in C#). Also, there is no integer that serves as the identity element when performing _concatenation_. If you attempt to concatenate a zero, you will be adding the charactor `0` to the end (or begining).

Comment: Integer addition and char concatenation have not that much in common. Where do you think I am comparing those?

Answer (score 6):

A `char` by definition has a length of one character. Empty simply doesn't fit the bill.

Don't run into confusion between a `char` and a `string` of max length 1. They sure look similar, but are very different beasts.

Comment: This makes `char` sound like a `string` whose length is restricted to 1. It's not. The key point is that `char` is a value type.

Comment: No, I'm not confusing it, this is the reason for my question. Should there not be an empty char, just like there is a null reference?

Comment: @dbt: The value type approach seems to make the most sense. But still I think a null value would make sense, but here the `?` comes in, which does not provide the semantics I would expect from a char null value. But keeping to what already is out there is often a very good idea, so it behaves mostly like C++ or Java and developers do not have to rethink that much.

Comment: @dtb Well, I wrote *"They sure look similar, but are very different beasts."*, so making them sound alike was not my intention