# What is the intent of this string.Split() line?

Tags: c#, string

What is the equivalent of this line in C#?

```
// In Java:
string[] split = val.Split("\u0000");
```

I know that:

1. The Java [split function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) takes a regular expression.
2. "\u0000" is the null character in Java.
3. In C#, when you pass null into string.Split it has special meaning. Using `"my example string".Split(null)` means to split on any white space character.

So, is the above line splitting a string on a null character, or is it shorthand for splitting the string on any white space character? If the former, how would I construct a split in C# to split on a null character?

Comment: In Java, this just splits on the null (ASCII 0) character.  If 0 is special in a C# string, I've got no idea.  I'd just try it and see what it does.

Comment: @markspace - It doesn't compile. The C# split function takes an array of strings or an array of chars for the delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the comment from @markspace and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670505/why-is-there-no-char-empty-like-string-empty) held the key:

```
string[] split = val.Split(new char[] { '\0' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

In C#, the split function takes a char array. The null char is specified as '\0'.

Also, in Java the default behavior is to remove the empty entries, hence the reason for the additional `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter.