# Stripping Character From String

Tags: c#

I have a code which sends a POST request to a web application and parses the response.

I'm sending the request with following code:

byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues("https://example.com", "POST", formData);

Converting `byte` data to `string` with this:

```
string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
```

`responsefromserver` equals something like this: `"abcd"`

I want to strip `"` characters. Therefore, I'm using following method:

```
Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver.Replace('"', ''));
```

But `''` shows me this error: `Empty character literal`

When I try to use `string.Empty` instead of `''` , I get this error: `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'`

What should I do to strip `"` characters from my string?

Comment: Use `responsefromserver.Replace("\"", string.Empty)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no [`Char.Empty` like there is a `String.Empty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670505/why-is-there-no-char-empty-like-string-empty), so you'll need to use the overload of `String.Replace` which accepts a `String` for both arguments.

You will need to escape the double quotes, so it should be :

```
Replace("\"", "");
```

Or:

```
Replace("\"", String.Empty);
```

Comment: One of the overloads for `Replace` accepts a `Char`, but to use replace with a string replacement, you need to use the 2nd overload, which expects a string as the first argument.

Comment: Edited your answer to improve it, did not seem worthwhile to create a new answer that arrives at the same solution. Cheers.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for it, never noticed that overload

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

```
responsefromserver.Replace("\"", "");//escaping the "

responsefromserver.Replace('"', '\0'); //null symbol <- not reccomended, only to allow you to use the char overload. It will NOT remove the " but replace with a null symbol!
responsefromserver.Replace('"', (char)0); // same as above in another format
```

In your case you could use Trim: this has the added bonus of removing the character only from the first/last place of the string allowing the rest of it to contain ":

```
responsefromserver.Trim('"'); // Remove first/last "
```