# Is there a reason '\0' is not supported in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

When I try to use `'\0'` as a character in F# it doesn't work.  Here is what I see:

[image]

I have read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670528/1959663) that `Char.MinValue` will accomplish the same thing though.

Is there any reason why `'\0'` is not supported?

Comment: I think the error is misleading. It's not a valid escape sequence. You just need three digits, but that has already been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is supported.
Character literals in F# are either a unicode character or the 16-bit unicode number. It's just that the backslash means it's a short or long escape sequence.

```
let A = '\u0041' // Capital letter A
```

The ASCII version of this is '\nnn'. So

```
let A = '\065' // Capital letter A
```

And so `\0` becomes `\000`.

```
assert('\000' = Char.MinValue) // true
```

Please note that the unicode specifier is in hex, while the short sequence is in decimal.

`DEC(65) = HEX(41)`

Answer (score 6):

The [F# specification](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) describes the grammar for char literals:

**3.5 Strings and Characters**

> regexp escape-char=  '\' ["\'ntbrafv]
>
> regexp non-escape-chars=  '\' [^"\'ntbrafv]
>
> regexp simple-char-char= | (any char except '\n' '\t' '\r' '\b' '\a'
>   '\f' '\v' ' \")
>
> regexp unicodegraph-short = '\''u' hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit
>
> regexp unicodegraph-long=  '\''U' hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit
>   hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit hexdigit
>
> regexp trigraph = '\' digit-char digit-char digit-char
>
> regexp char-char= | simple-char-char | escape-char | trigraph |
>   unicodegraph-short

`\0` matches none of these - if you want the null character you can use

```
let c = '\000'
```

or `Char.MinValue`